# How to secure Outlook Web Access against Brute Force attack?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, groups, user-accounts, brute-force-attacks

I'd like to secure **Outlook Web Access** with **Exchange 2010** against a **brute force attack** using **account lockout**.

What is the best way to do this?

I have the following group policy:

Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies\Account Lockout Policy\

- Account Lockout duration 10 mins
- Account lockout threshold 5 attempts
- Reset Account lockout counter after 10 mins

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's good enough if you have a reasonable password policy. If people can have a password of `1`, that's probably going to be a problem.

You've rate limited brute forcing the password to 1 password every 2 minutes. At that rate guessing a 7 character, all numbers password would take 19 years of straight hacking on average... and that's a pretty crappy password.

Comment: Yeah. And welcome to a DDOS world where your people are locked out constantly ;)

Answer (score 5):

While what Chris S says its true, you have opened yourself up to a DOS attack.  I can't break into your accounts, but I can lock them all out permanently.  I just keep on doing wrong password attempts, indefinitely.  One bad attempt per user, every 2 minutes isn't much.

You need something monitoring your logs for invalid attempts, and eventually block that IP address at the firewall for a period of time.

How to set that up is highly dependent on your infrastructure (logging, firewall, etc), and your usage patterns.  For instance if the same IP address makes a invalid attempt on 2-3 accounts, you may want to block that IP for a few days.  If its one account, you may only want to block that IP once its done 10 invalid attempts in an hour, for two hours.

Comment: You make a good point. I've decided to make a new question to focus on the DOS issue. http://serverfault.com/questions/227319/how-do-i-prevent-against-a-dos-attack-through-outlook-web-access